# Rails 4 Active Record uniq by one column query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Lets say I have a model `Account` with columns `:email, :name, etc`. Emails are not unique. What I want is to add a **chainable** `scope` that selects rows with distinct emails but with all other fields. By 'chainable' I mean that I could do like this: `Account.uniq_by_email.where(bla bla)`.

What I've tried:

1. With `select`:

   ```
   def self.uniq_by_email
     select('distinct email')
   end
   ```

   Doesn't work for me as it selects only email field.
2. With `group`

   ```
   def self.uniq_by_email
     group(:email)
   end
   ```

   This almost what I want: I can chain and it selects all fields. But there is a strange thing about `count` method: it, as you already guessed, returns a hash of email counts. But I want it to return "simple" `ActiveRecord_Relation` where `count` returns just a count not a hash. Is that possible to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My basic idea is to select only the first entry in every group of email.
Make it easy, I create a scope like this instead of using a class method:

```
scope :uniq_by_email, -> { joins("JOIN (
                                   SELECT MIN(id) as min_id
                                   FROM accounts
                                   GROUP BY email
                                  ) AS temp
                                  ON temp.min_id = id") }
```

From this you can do something like chainable as you described:

```
Account.uniq_by_email.where(bla bla)
```

Comment: tx, that what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use group by, but then u can count as,

```
 Account.uniq_by_email.where(bla bla).flatten.count
```

Comment: Yes sure, but that is not a solution for me. This `uniq_by_email` is used for multiple steps filtering depending on conditions. So at the end of the query I don't want to discover whether `uniq_by_email` was called or not. I just want to get count of found records